# Is Docker build cache automatically purged?

Tags: docker

I'm unable to find out whether the Docker's local build cache is automatically purged or not.

And if it is purged, how often? Is this something we can configure? Is there an age limit, or total cache size limit?

Please note, this question is not about how to bypass cache while building images, nor how to manually purge cache, nor how to leverage caching mechanism to speed up Docker builds. These questions are already widely documented. The purpose of this question is to find out how Docker internally manages its build cache. Does it live forever if not purged manually? Does it expire on its own? How?

Comment: My docker build cache just disappeared now for unknown reason. I did change the build context (the files within the folder), but it should not have invalidated the entirety of the cache, as my `COPY` statements were put last in the Dockerfile. So, it's either a bug or the cache got automatically purged. There was plenty of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

docker's build cache is based on `image`s that you have locally.  images are never automatically deleted, so in essence the build cache is never deleted

the way docker decides as to whether to use the cache involves checking if the previous layer and the command being run are the same

if you delete an image that would have been used to satisfy a cache you could consider that "clearing the cache" (additionally `docker system prune -f` will remove any anonymous images which may also be cache components)

Comment: So there is an infinite cache, until it potentially uses up all available disk space? Do you have references? These would make your answer very valuable.

Comment: correct yes -- there isn't really anything to reference as that's just how it works (there is no specification) -- you could read the source though it's quite complicated.  this answer is from experience: both as a user and from contributing to the caching code myself: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/35582